# Metadata navigation in List View Web Part

Tags: list, list-view, list-view-web-part

I have list and list view web part on a page which points to default view of that list. I have enabled metadata navigation on my list, and my question is: is it possible to show/enable metadata navigation in that list view web part as well?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my blog post http://davidlozzi.com/2012/02/20/sharepoint-metadata-filter-page-web-parts/

Comment: Not sure why the downvote... what's asked is not possible OOTB, so the use of some custom code will be required.

Comment: Possibly down voted by someone because you didn't post a "Good Answer". See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers for an explanation of what I mean. Link rot over time would negate your answer for others who come in looking, as an example.

Comment: @DavidLozzi I agree with MAllen22842, If you can add some details from the link it will beneift other readers.